RabbitMQ 3.12.13 head_message_timestamp is null
I am using the RabbitMQ API in version 3.12.13 to retrieve the head message timestamp for all queues, but the API is returning null for most (but not all) queues.
We have the value set in our rabbitmq.conf file:
message_interceptors.incoming.set_header_timestamp.overwrite = true
and I am calling the API at {rabbitmqURL}:{port}/api/queues
Has anyone else had this issue?
Thanks
